# Special Characters handling in REST API SOQL C# HttpClient

Tags: soql, rest-api

My Setup. C#.net Project, Rest Api to Salesforce Dev Org.
Received Error on following Query

```
SELECT ID FROM PRODUCT2 WHERE ProductCode = 'M5Z55UP#ABC'

<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<Errors>\n    
<Error>\n        
<errorCode>MALFORMED_QUERY</errorCode>\n        
<message>\nPRODUCT2 WHERE ProductCode = &apos;M5Z55UP\n                                    ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:52\nline 1:52 mismatched character &apos;&lt;EOF&gt;&apos; expecting &apos;&apos;&apos;</message>\n    </Error>\n</Errors>\n
```

Apearenty, API request to Salesforce is not Allowing # as a special Character.

```
my.salesforce.com/services/data/v46.0/query/?q=SELECT ID FROM PRODUCT2 WHERE ProductCode = 'M5Z55UP#ABC'
```

I tried Url Builder, "\" etc. but did not work.
How to Handle Such Characters?
 Currently I am stuck with # characters but I am sure there are many more.
Thanks,
Dhananjay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encode your query, so it will look somehow like:

```
SELECT+Id+FROM+PRODUCT2+WHERE+ProductCode+=+%27M5Z55UP%23ABC%27
```

The spaces can be parsed both with **+** and **%20** encodings.

Comment: for C# I used HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url); to handle #, is there anything else that I might need to handle? I am new to salesforce SOQL so I am trying to understand where It might fail. Your Answer is perfect, So I'll wait for some more feedback on this. and then mark it as Answered! Thanks.

Comment: It helped me when I first used SOQL through the REST API, so I think it's all you should be aware of.